# Adding a 'section' to the backend menu

Tags: posts, theme-customizer

[image]I have been learning how to create themes.

Recently I saw a theme that had a section in the menu for a 'services'. inside this looked like the post 'section' and there were options to create several posts which all then appeared on one page - the services page in this case.

How would I go about creating such a menu item? I searched, but I could not find anything useful. I don't want anyone to write my code, but I would like someone please to suggest what to look for.

Many thanks

E

Comment: These are called Custom Post Types. You can learn about them here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: sorry it took so long to reply - thanks, that's really helpful